# How can i pass a component ref to redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.myRef = React.createRef();
}
render() {
  return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
}
```

I can create a component ref like this after I render a component. What I need is keeping this component ref in the redux store. I can keep it as a state variable but redux throws an error something like this:

> Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance

Is there any way to hold a component ref as a global variable in application?

Deep copy of ref object, parsing JSON string didn't work...

Comment: do you mind explaining *why* you are trying to do this?

Comment: sure, I have rendered posts and after I rendered posts according to the content of the post I might need to update previous posts. If I have a post which has to be updated I want to keep it in the redux store. Then I can update it while another post is rendering. There is too much code to send...

Comment: it sounds like it is against of the react logic but i couldn't find another way to do it.

Comment: you should be editing the *data* that is then rendered, not the rendered element directly.

Comment: you cant. i guess. keep the object which is used to render the posts in redux store and modify that, the other post will automatically re-render with the changes.

Comment: thanks for the answers... as I understood passing the ref is not the proper way. I think to create a data object in the redux store for post components which have to be updated by next posts is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use withRef feature in connect

```
  export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps, null, {withRef: true})(myComponent);
```

for reference look in below link example having use of withRef

[sample code link](https://jsfiddle.net/jacobworrel/anqjxq95/30/)